# How to make my Ionic Android application function online and offlne

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have been working on a Fonic Framework project and the data and images have come directly from my server and database because am using my custom APIs. How would I make my data and images function offline? That is when their's no network, users can still see images and data pulled when they were online. How do I go about this synchronization?

Comment: Store datas to a local Database => cordova Sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question spreads through a wide scope depending on how much data you want the user to allow browse offline.

However, If you want something more than the normal caching `ionic` provides, you will have to look at a data storage, like Sqlite

Following links will give you an idea

[HTML5 Offline Mobile App Using Ionic and PouchDB](http://www.webspeaks.in/2015/03/html5-offline-mobile-app-using-ionic-pouchdb.html)

[ionic framework sync data and work offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610330/ionic-framework-sync-data-and-work-offline)